# android open source

Tags: android

While I'm trying to debug a program, at a moment I'm asked to Attach Source! The fact that I don't have the source code, it might be the cause of my program's crash? Or the open source codes has nothing to do with my programs crash...please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being asked to attach source for the core SDK classes. Don't bother with it as you won't want to step through any of that anyhow

Comment: No, you  made it crash. Anytime it moves out of your code into the SDK, it's usually the result of an exception. :-) If this answered your question, kindly accept this answer